# How to find the totals by groups?

Tags: r

I'm trying to summarize some data by groups with finding the totals.

```
library(hflights)
head(hflights)
hflights_df <- tbl_df(hflights)
hflights_df$ActualElapsedTime<-as.numeric(hflights_df$ActualElapsedTime)
hflights_df %>%
  group_by("Year", "Month") %>%
  sum(ActualElapsedTime, na.rm=T)
```

Error in function_list[k] : object 'ActualElapsedTime' not found

How would I go about correcting this?

Comment: Either `%>% summarize(x=sum(ActualElapsedTime,na.rm=T))` or `%>% sum(.$ActualElapsedTime,na.rm=T)`.

Comment: `sum` is a base R function...you are probably looking for `summarise(sum(..., na.rm=T))`

Answer (score 1):

Your final row should be:

```
hflights_df %>%
  group_by("Year", "Month") %>%
  summarise(x = sum(ActualElapsedTime, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   "Year" [?]
  `"Year"` `"Month"`        x
     <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>
1     Year     Month 28952224
```

Comment: I would check your output and see if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `dplyr` and base R functions.  If you're going to use `dplyr`, you'll need to use `summarize` to get the sum for each group.

Note that you don't need to quote the arguments in `group_by` when using `dplyr` interactively.

```
library(hflights)
library(dplyr)

hflights %>% 
  group_by(Year, Month) %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(ActualElapsedTime, na.rm=T))

# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Year [?]
    Year Month   total
   <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1  2011     1 2335093
 2  2011     2 2022033
 3  2011     3 2492071
 4  2011     4 2388752
 5  2011     5 2479506
 6  2011     6 2534577
 7  2011     7 2648940
 8  2011     8 2563005
 9  2011     9 2304998
10  2011    10 2389236
11  2011    11 2327190
12  2011    12 2466823
```

Comment: I'm only getting a total number of 28952224 it's not in groups with the above code. Do you know why I get a different output?

Comment: I would try starting a new session, updating libraries and running it again.  This works on my instance with `dplyr 0.7.4` and `hflights 0.1`, `R 3.4.4`